# Collision stop between two Objects

Tags: java, collision-detection

Below is my code that detects collision between two objects, setting a `boolean` to `true` every time my player collides with the wall:

```
private boolean collide(){
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++){
        if(this.getBounds().intersects(handler.object.get(i).getBounds()) && handler.object.get(i).getId() != ID.Player && handler.object.get(i).getId().equals(ID.Wall)){
            System.out.println("COLLIDEEEEE");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My intent is to have the player stop moving upon collision.
Right now my Code for the player Movement looks like this:

```
public void tick() {
    if (Var.A == true && Var.ableToMove == true) {
        Var.OffsetX += Var.speed;

    }
    if (Var.D == true && Var.ableToMove == true) {
        Var.OffsetX -= Var.speed;

    }
```

What i now want to do is, I want the player stop upon colliding the wall.
I would really appreciate if anyone of you could help me.

Comment: two* objects :D

Comment: What kind of *help* do you asking for? Your `collide()` method seems to work fine.

Comment: What do you mean by the player stopping? What would that actually entail?

Comment: My answer now is how i can make the Player object stop moving through the Wall. So he cant pass the wall.

Comment: @MaxiKeller then maybe you should tell us more about *Player* ant it's *moving*

Comment: What i was already trying is to set the speed of the player *= -1; but then the player is stuck inside of the wall

Comment: I will upload my play move function

Comment: public void tick() {
  if (Var.A == true && Var.ableToMove == true) {
   Var.OffsetX += Var.speed;
 
  }
  if (Var.D == true && Var.ableToMove == true) {
   Var.OffsetX -= Var.speed;
  
  }

Comment: So this is how i  move the player right now. And what i want to happen is that my Player stops on colliding with the Wall

Comment: How can i edit it?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(this.getBounds().intersects(handler.object.get(i).getBounds())
```

seems fine to detect collision between this (the player) and other elements.

but this doesn't seem fine :

```
handler.object.get(i).getId() != ID.Player && handler.object.get(i).getId().equals(ID.Wall)){
```

1) It is not consistent.
The first comparison compares the reference of the id objects :

```
handler.object.get(i).getId() != ID.Player
```

The second one compares the id objects according to the `equals()` method :

```
handler.object.get(i).getId().equals(ID.Wall))
```

You should use the same way in both cases.
You don't specify if you use String for id but `String`s should be compared with `equals()` as a general way.

2)You should not need to make two comparisons.

Assuming that ID.Player and ID.Wall are two distinct values,  if `handler.object.get(i).getId().equals(ID.Player)` is true, it means that 
`handler.object.get(i).getId().equals(ID.Wall)` is false.

`handler.object.get(i).getId().equals(ID.Wall)` should be enough.

Comment: Ok i will try that. Thanks